# Process Http POST with JSON & Image in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am creating an API to recieve and process data from phone app using PHP.
I can successfully process most calls but, am struggling with how to receive POST with image and json in it.

I have the following code in my API.php file:

```
//Make sure that it is a POST request.
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}

//Make sure that the content type of the POST request has been set to application/json
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
}

//Receive the RAW post data.
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post data from JSON.
$json = json_decode($content, true); 

//If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
if(!is_array($json)){
    throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can file a Base64 encoding and send it as a json field

```
$path = 'image.png';
$info = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

and function to decode

```
function base64ToImage($base64String, $outputFile) {
    $file = fopen($outputFile, "wb");
    $data = explode(',', $base64String);
    fwrite($file, base64_decode($data[1]));
    fclose($file);

    return $outputFile;
}
```